# Calculation of parking charges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

tableTime:

```
ID  Time in    Time out  Vehicle Type
1   10:30      11:20     bike
2   10:40      12:30     car
```

table_charges:

```
Id  Vehicle Type  Rate
1   bike          50
2   Car           100
```

Help me to write a query that returns the total duration and cost in two separate columns by applying the rate with respect to type of vehicle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you write any query for achieve it? if you are getting error in written query then please post here.Else try to write a query first.

Comment: Please provide at least some scripts for the database schema or even better, use http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

For Duration you can first convert `[Time in]` and `[Time out]` to `DateTime` and then just subtract

`DATEDIFF(hour,  cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time in] as datetime), cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time out] as datetime) )`

Final query is :

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, t1.[Time in], t1.[Time out], t1.[Vehicle Type]
, cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time IN]  as  datetime) as tin
, cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time out]  as  datetime) as tout
, DATEDIFF(hour,  cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time in] as datetime), cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time out] as datetime) ) 
as Duration
, (DATEDIFF(hour,  cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time in] as datetime), cast('2013-01-01 ' + t1.[Time out] as datetime) ) ) * 
( select rate from t2 where t2.[Vehicle Type] = t1.[Vehicle Type] )
as Charge 

FROM t1
```

This is     **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8adba/10)**

Answer (score 0):

Give you a **[SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa9b0/3)**. 
You can use same way to ask question too. I think this can help you to charge more money, since 1 minute extra will be considered as an extra hour.....

```
select A.id, 
       Time_in, 
       Time_out,
       A.Vehicle_type,
       CEILING(DATEDIFF(Minute, Time_in, Time_out)/60.0) as Park_Duration_Hours,
       B.Rate * CEILING(DATEDIFF(Minute, Time_in, Time_out)/60.0) as TotalCharge
from TableTime A
left join TableCharges B
on A.Vehicle_Type = B.Vehicle_Type
```

Comment: THNX SOOOOO MCH DEAR, REALLY GR8 FULL,,,  MAY BE I NEED SOME MORE UR GUIDANCE :)